# Unchanged Elastic Beanstalk transitions to RED health

Tags: monitoring, amazon-web-services, tomcat, elastic-beanstalk

I've got an application running on Elastic Beanstalk that seems to randomly transition to RED. The App is running just fine and has been for a while *(it is also not crashing)* but every once in a while it transitions through YELLO to RED and is inaccessible for .

I'd like to know why this is happening, the logs do not indicate why it might be doing this. It looks like it *could* be Amazon updating the beanstalk snapshot, but there is no indication in the logs or even history that it is being done.

Does anyone know what causes this and what I can do to prevent it?